# Help users to ask objective questions about architecture

Tags: discussion, questions, faq-for-site, off-topic

I think that software architecture is a very important part of complex applications like games. Therefore questions about software architecture and design should definitely be part of Game Development.

Many users ask questions about their own architectures, but unfortunately, often in a subjective and opinion based way. Those questions cannot be answered objectively and are considered off-topic on our site, which is correct in my opinion.

Quotations of subjective written questions about game architecture.

> What refactor or re-design would you recommend to allow the world class to accept ANY object? ([Design issue: World class only contains Rigidbodies but custom objects need further updating](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55327/design-issue-world-class-only-contains-rigidbodies-but-custom-objects-need-furt))
>
> my question is about situation when there is action between players at game (like items exchange, players money/tokens billing change). I know this depends on many factors, but please look at one of solutions below. ([How game engines handle transactions between users?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29654/how-game-engines-handle-transactions-between-users))
>
> To summarise, given the described architecture of my game, how can I appropriately handle my game logic? ([Game editor architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/game-editor-architecture))
>
> What do you think, is this as bad as I think it is? How would you address it? ([What part of my engine should load images and fonts?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47664/what-part-of-my-engine-should-load-images-and-fonts))
>
> There is more to it than this, but I just wanted to highlight the central idea of what I was doing, and wanted opinions on whether a cyclical approach like this ([Need opinions on my component based design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61196/need-opinions-on-my-component-based-design))

But I saw multiple cases where users had real problems about architectures in game development, but had trouble formulating their questions in an objective way. To not (from their view, surprisingly) close questions of these users, I suggest collecting tips for formulating questions about architectures well, and providing them in the help center.

This is because I feel that many of those questions do target a specific and objectively answerable issue. But it is not always easy to hunt the actual issue down to the core problem and extract the needed information when writing a question. For now, we can just refer to the [help page about on topic and off topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but we can't easily give advice for doing better.

What do you think, could we find some simple guide lines for writing questions which are objectivly answerable and add them to the FAQ?

Comment: What type of advice are you thinking? What sort of advice would be specific to subjective *architecture* questions that would not already apply to subjective questions in general (that is not also question-specific and therefor not appropriate for a FAQ page versus a comment on the question itself)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what these 'real problems' are. Are one or more of the questioners in the examples you posted struggling with these problems? Could you give an example of an underlying issue that wasn't addressed properly?